# Dotnet core installation error on win 2010

Tags: .net, .net-core

While installing dotnet core 1.0 on win 2010 I get the below error. I have VS 2012 installed on `C:` and istalled VS 2015 community edition on `D:`.
Full error log could not be posted due to size.

```
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1029'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1029' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1031'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1031' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1036'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1036' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1040'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1040' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1041'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1041' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1042'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1042' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1045'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1045' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1046'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1046' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1049'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1049' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\1055'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_1055' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\2052'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_2052' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise\3082'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015EnterpriseExists_3082' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\enterprise'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1028'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1028' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1029'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1029' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1031'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1031' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1036'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1036' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1040'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1040' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1041'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1041' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1042'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1042' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1045'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1045' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1046'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1046' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1049'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1049' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\1055'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_1055' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\2052'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_2052' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional\3082'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015ProfessionalExists_3082' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\professional'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015UpdateVersionExists' to value 1
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting string variable 'VS2015UpdateVersion' to value '14.0.25420'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1028'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1028' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1029'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1029' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1031'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1031' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1036'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1036' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1040'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1040' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1041'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1041' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1042'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1042' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1045'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1045' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1046'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1046' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1049'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1049' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\1055'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_1055' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\2052'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_2052' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor\3082'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VS2015WebExpressExists_3082' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\14.0\xcor'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WebToolsVSInstalled' to value 1
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\Web Tools\Servicing\14.0\VWDExpress14'
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WebToolsVWDInstalled' to value 0
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WSRVSExists' to value 1
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition '(NOT(RelationType = "Patch") AND NOT (WixBundleAction >= 4))' evaluates to false.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition 'DotNetCLIProductVersion_x86 = v4.0.3121' evaluates to false.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition 'DotNetCLIProductVersion_x64 = v4.0.3121' evaluates to false.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {C5A4ABA3-1ABA-3EF8-B2D5-C3FA37F59738}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.10609.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {2D170B66-A905-385C-93E0-20A47812B777}, scope: PerMachine, version: 3.4.4.1321, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i103: Detected related package: {603DCF17-E958-3A31-AFED-919086709DB6}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.1.11107.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition '(WixBundleAction >= 3)' evaluates to true.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: SetupBlocked_Install, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: AspNetCoreModule_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: AspNetCoreModule_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: ANCM_IISExpress_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: ANCM_IISExpress_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetCLI_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetCLI_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetVersionManager_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: NuGetVS14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: NuGetVWD14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVS14_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsExtensionsVWD14_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVS14_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: WebToolsAzureVWD14_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVS14_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: DotNetToolsVWD14_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: Preparation_ASPNET, state: Absent, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i101: Detected package: SetupBlocked_Uninstall, state: Present, cached: None
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(NetFx45Release < 378675) OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to true.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR VS2015DevEnvExists OR VS2015WebExpressExists OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to true.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR (((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420) OR (VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420) OR (VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420)) OR (VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion >= v14.0.25420)) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to true.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i052: Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015CommunityExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015ProfessionalExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015EnterpriseExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015WebExpressExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists))) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR (WixBundleAction=2)' evaluates to false.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]e000: Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 may not be completely installed. Please repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, then install this product again.
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]e000: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015CommunityExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015ProfessionalExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015EnterpriseExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015WebExpressExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists))) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR (WixBundleAction=2)
[1544:12C0][2016-07-24T07:54:48]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Comment: "Please repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 3"

Comment: Had tried this couple of time, but same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will be able to do it by running this command `.\DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1` on powershell or cmd. I get that from:

> http://forums.asp.net/t/2099735.aspx?Cannot+install+DotNetCore+1+0+0+VS2015Tools+Preview2

Comment: Thanks, It was real help. You saved my day.

Comment: Thank you. Was such an annoyance repairing the installation of VS2015 a bunch of times.

Comment: After installation with "SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1", I still got a fail message. But inside visual studio everything is working fine so far. Thanks a lot.